# How to compare elements of unequal length String arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I compare the elements of two different String arrays, of unequal lengths, to each other one-by-one.

```
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Scanner;


    public class ArrayComparison {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String list1[] = {"m99076", "m10141", "o87909", "o90876", "l17237"};
            String list2[] = {"1", "foo", "1", "m10141", "s3002", "bar", "1", "u39392", "n6233", "fubar", "1", "o87909", "z039"};


            for(int i = 0; [i] < list1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; [j] < list2; j++){

                }if (list1[i] == list2[j]);
                System.out.println("The values are equal");
            } else
                list1[i] != list2[j];
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Code formatting would help. Some blocks are not nested the way you probably want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would loop through the arrays like this, comparing each String using the ".equals()" comparison method.

```
     String list1[] = {"m99076", "m10141", "o87909", "o90876", "l17237"};
     String list2[] = {"1", "foo", "1", "m10141", "s3002", "bar", "1", "u39392", "n6233", "fubar", "1", "o87909", "z039"};

     for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
         for (int a = 0; a < list2.length; a++) {

             if (list1[i].equals(list2[a])) {
                 System.out.println("\"" + list1[i] + "\" is equal to \"" + list2[a] + "\"");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("\"" + list1[i] + "\" is not equal to \"" + list2[a] + "\"");
             }

         }
     }
```

The output of the following starts like this:

```
"m99076" is not equal to "1"
"m99076" is not equal to "foo"
"m99076" is not equal to "1"
... lots of lines redacted, until it gets to the first equals ...
"m10141" is equal to "m10141"
```

Full output of the program here: http://pastebin.com/ayaMA0Fk

Also, a lot of your syntax is incorrect. You should read up on the basics of Java syntax here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11cheatsheet/

Comment: Did you notice that `list1` and `list2` have different lengths?

Comment: @iRuth: Yes, but sequentially comparing the elements of two arrays that have unequal lengths doesn't make sense. You could only compare the elements in that fashion up to the length of the shortest array. I am not very sure what the user wants to accomplish.

Comment: The question is unclear, but OP probably wants to compare all elements with all other elements (not just matching indexes).

Comment: @Thilo yes I would like to compare all indexes, I am trying to make this complicated for me so I can learn. I realize I have syntax errors, I am trying to get the code right first. I would like to make use of a double array thats why I wrote the program as I did.

Comment: @LucasHarrison Please update your original question to be more specific. And "double array" isn't a real term. Do you mean a multi-dimensional array, or using two arrays? Do you want to compare one by one? For example, compare the first element of the first array to every element in the second array, then the second element of the first array to every element in the second array, and so on? If so, where do you want this information to be stored. These are all questions you should answer in your original post.

Comment: @Connorelsea I mean using two arrays, furthermore I would like to compare one by one. I want this information to be stored in the console using something like:                                                                                                                                  if (list1[i] == list2[i]) {
       System.out.println("The array index is equal");
      } else{
       System.out.println("The array index is not equal"); 
       }

Comment: @LucasHarrison If this worked or didn't work, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Connorelsea"l17237 It works! Your awesome, thank you. How would I add a finally to a try catch block if I wanted to add that to the program as well?

Comment: You only need a try-catch block when you may be catching an Exception. The format of a try-catch-finally block is "try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { ... } finally { ... }", except spread over multiple lines of course. To learn more about this, visit this tutorial page and click "next" to see the sections on catch and finally blocks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: @Connorelsea  Awesome, I love to learn, I'll check it out. Thank you so much.